# How can I print a string in C such that it will show characters like \n, \o, etc?

Tags: c, string, special-characters

I need to check if my program is correctly inputting these characters in my strings, so how can I see a "raw" string with these characters not parsed but actually shown?

Comment: Does your program have the characters hardcoded into the strings, or do you get the input from the user/from a file?

Comment: I think you need to clarify the question a little... If you have some input that contains an _actual_ newline, you want to print it as `\n`?

Comment: @Geesh_SO can you please clarify the question? An example would be better than a page long explanation.

Comment: Usually a debugger provides the ability to inspect the content of your variables (including strings).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read input (from file or from user) the special escape codes are *not* parsed. It's only in string and character literals in the source that the *compiler* treats those specially.

**Edit:** Simple example program with input and output to show what I'm talking about.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    char input[32];

    printf("Enter input: ");
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);

    /* Remove trailing newline */
    if (input[strlen(input) - 1] == '\n')
        input[strlen(input) - 1] = '\0';

    printf("input is \"%s\"\n", input);

    return 0;
}
```

Example run of the above program:

```
Enter input: foo\nbar\thello
input is "foo\nbar\thello"
```

The function `fgets` leaves the actual newline at the end of the string. However, the sequences `\n` and `\t` in the input does *not* get translated to newline or tab (respectively). That is because it's not the input or output functions that handles these special character sequences, but the compiler.

If you have those sequences inside a string or character literal in the source, then the compiler recognizes those and changes them to a proper newline, tab or whatever it is you wrote. However, as the compiler doesn't know anything about input read from a file or from a user, these sequences are *not* translated.

**Edit 2:** In case you wonder about how to show *literal* special characters in a string, then please see this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void print_raw_string(const char *str)
{
    while (*str != '\0')
    {
        if (isprint(*str))
            fputc(*str, stdout);
        else
        {
            switch (*str)
            {
                /* First check for known special sequences */
            case '\0':
                printf("\\0");
                break;
            case '\a':
                printf("\\a");
                break;
            case '\b':
                printf("\\b");
                break;
            case '\t':
                printf("\\t");
                break;
            case '\n':
                printf("\\n");
                break;
            case '\v':
                printf("\\v");
                break;
            case '\f':
                printf("\\f");
                break;
            case '\r':
                printf("\\r");
                break;

            default:
                /* None of the above, print it out as a hex escape sequence */
                printf("\\x%02x", *str);
                break;
            }
        }

        str++;
    }
}

int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    char input[32];

    printf("Enter input: ");
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);

    printf("Input is: ");
    print_raw_string(input);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

When running the program:

```
Enter input: foo    bar
Input is: foo\tbar\n
```

Comment: he wants to print those back on screen.

Comment: @Aniket It's doesn't matter, as it's not `printf` or other output functions that parses the string for these special sequences, it's the **compiler**.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, what does that compiler has to do with user input ? and are you saying I can't read a new line character ?

Comment: @mux If the user inputs a _literal_ newline then you will have a newline in the string. But if the user inputs the two characters \ and n then the input will contain those two characters and _not_ a newline.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg hence you can just check if the line contains a newline with `if((*ch) == '\n'){ putchar('\\'); putchar('n'); ch++}`. As far as I know, this is what the OP wants.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the OP wants **non-printing** characters to be visible. (IIRC this is a program in **The C Programming Language** by Ritchie and Kernighan)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I understand now what you're saying, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution would be to printout the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) values of what's in the string, this works regardless of it being a fixed string or coming from `stdin`:

```
char str[] = "A\tBC1\n";
int j;
for(j = 0; j<strlen(str); str++)
  printf("%#x ", str[j]);
```

Output:

```
>>0x41 0x9 0x42 0x43 0x31 0xA
```

From stdin:

```
fgets(str, 5, stdin);
for(j = 0; j<strlen(str); j++)
  printf("%#x ", str[j]);
```

Input/Output:

```
>> 1   2         <---- That's a tab between 1 and 2
>> 0x31 0x9 0x32 0xA
```

You can get fancy and escape the characters to show `\t` (0x9) and `\n` (0xA) instead of the raw values, but if you just want to verify that you're getting them, this should work (and be faster)

Answer (score 1):

You can either escape the characters, or write your own special routine like this:

```
void print_raw(const char *ch)
{
   char *d = ch;
   while(*d){
     switch(*d){
       case '\n':
           printf("\\n");
       break;
       case '\v':
           printf("\\n");
       break;
       case '\r':
       printf("\\r");
           break;
       case '\a':
       printf("\\a");
           break;
       case '\?':
       printf("\\?");
           break;
       case '\"':
       printf("\"");
           break;
       case '\t':
       printf("\\t");
           break;
       case '\b':
       printf("\\b");
           break;
       case '\f':
       printf("\\f");
           break;
       case '\\':
       printf("\\");
           break;
       case '\'':
       printf("\'");
           break;
       default:
          putchar(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to do 'printf("%s"'? All that work you do is not necessary.

Comment: `printf("%s")` will add the formatting to the string. That's what the OP doesn't want. He just wants to see the characters in a raw-format. Which means we have to print the non-printing characters.

Comment: That's not how I interpret the question.

Answer (score 0):

just print the string as a sequence of characters, something like:


str is your string:

```
char *ptr = str;
while(*ptr != 0)
{
   print("%02X", *ptr);
   ptr++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Printf doesn't do anything special with \n or such. Those character sequences are interpreted by the compiler. Try this:

```
$ cat foo.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
        return 1;
    printf("%d\n", (int)strlen(argv[1]));
    printf("%d\n", (int)strlen("\n"));
    printf("[%s]\n", argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
$ cc -Wall -O2 -o foo foo.c && ./foo '\n'
2
1
[\n]
$
```

Notice that I escape \n when calling foo because the shell interprets \ (differently) if it's not escaped.